# S lock on KEY is not released

Tags: sql-server, locking, database-deadlocks

I faced with key deadlock when 1 process executes delete query and 2 process makes select query.
[image]

After some investigation I found out that in process 2 with select query occurs extra S Key lock  and it is not released. This extra lock occurs even  in empty table.
Below i puted log example from empty table

```
66 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 6:1614680850:0  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 66 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 6:1:16596  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 66 acquiring S lock on KEY: 6:72057594126925824 (fca2a895105d) (class bit1000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 66 releasing lock on PAGE: 6:1:16596 

(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Process 66 releasing lock on OBJECT: 6:1614680850:0
```

This lock is not released and I guess, is cause of deadlock

> S lock on KEY: 6:72057594126925824 (fca2a895105d) (class bit1000000 ref1)
>   appears and does not releases resources

Additionaly important notes which can help:

- Lock stops to reproduse afte recreate key index
- this lock appears after deleting any items in table and reproduces in every select query
- index on table is just simple clustered index by Id
- issolation level is read commited

Here is index pk-404 defenition:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK-404] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = 
ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is deadlock xml:

```
<deadlock-list>
<deadlock victim="process42dfb48c8">
    <process-list>
        <process id="process42dfb48c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594123845632 (a0db81c60a00)" waittime="7738" ownerId="175339832" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-01-08T13:37:22.097" XDES="0x46fd24f20" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="13560" status="suspended" spid="64" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-08T13:37:22.100" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-08T13:37:22.097" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.097" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CHARNIAUSKI" hostpid="25760" loginname="S-1-9-3-4196599067-1192152927-2838817951-2017651452" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="175339832" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1166" stmtend="6160" sqlhandle="0x020000004fb4de1aaf9674f427de347416278bb96066c87b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown         </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown         </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@$t_perm_tp_0 nvarchar(7),@$t_perm_tp_1 nvarchar(12),@$t_iden_list_2 ntext,@$t_ip_addr_3 nvarchar(3),@$t_cur_user_id_4 char(32),@$t_pwarn_5 nvarchar(24),@$Crtr char(32),@$Mngr char(32),@$Ownr char(32),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_created_by_id_9 nvarchar(4),@$intCanGet int,@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_current_state_11 nvarchar(16),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_destination_system_12 nvarchar(15),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_id_13 nvarchar(22),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_itemtype_id_14 nvarchar(8),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_locked_by_id_15 nvarchar(4),@SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_modified_by_id_16 nvarchar(4))SELECT  [SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS].[CREATED_BY_ID] [CREATED_BY_ID], fk0.keyed_name AS created_by_id_$_keyed_name, @SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS_created_by_id_9 AS created_by_id_$_type, @$intCanGet AS created_by_id_$_permission, [SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS].[CREATED_ON] [CREATED_ON], [SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS].[CSS] [CSS], [SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS].[CURRENT_STATE] [CURRENT_STATE], fk1.keyed_name AS current_state_$_keyed_name, @SYNCHRONIZATION_        </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process4021d5088" taskpriority="0" logused="75192" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594123845632 (34ae5dff07bc)" waittime="838" ownerId="175321005" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-01-08T13:37:20.910" XDES="0x46fec0f20" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="5968" status="suspended" spid="69" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-08T13:37:29.003" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-08T13:37:29.003" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.003" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="CHARNIAUSKI" hostpid="25760" loginname="S-1-9-3-4196599067-1192152927-2838817951-2017651452" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="175321005" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="28" stmtend="136" sqlhandle="0x02000000a2bf4a1340bcb59dc4a28a98762fb48a43cbf6a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown         </frame>
                <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown         </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@id char(32))DELETE FROM [SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS] WHERE  [ID] = @id         </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594123845632" dbid="6" objectname="KHI-SP11-Rel-0103.SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS" indexname="pk4044" id="lock3d7a81600" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594123845632">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process4021d5088" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process42dfb48c8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594123845632" dbid="6" objectname="KHI-SP11-Rel-0103.SYNCHRONIZATION_STATUS" indexname="pk4044" id="lock438cc6280" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594123845632">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process42dfb48c8" mode="S"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process4021d5088" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: Add the deadlock XML to your question.

Comment: This can happen if you have very small table ( ie. Sql server can accommodate  the table into  2-3 data pages  ) . Sql server read a whole page at a time. To read or delete the data Sql server locks the whole page and if table is small the entire table will be locked. Using Row Lock in your queries you can avoid this situation.

Comment: uppdated with deadlock XML

Comment: What is the definition of the index pk4044? what is the full query non-deleting session running?  Have you considered READ COMITTED SNAPSHOT or SNAPSHOT ISOLATION to eliminate the S locks?

Comment: David Browme, I updated answer. and we cannot use SNAPSHOT isolation level, only in read commited